# How to sum up a column from a text file in FORTRAN?

Tags: fortran

I want to sum up an entire column from my text file with a defined format. I am able to read and print my text file but have troubles with summarizing. Here is my code:

```
program sum
implicit none
character, Dimension(259)::a,b
real,Dimension(259)::c
integer, Dimension(25)::d
integer::e, xyz

!read the existing file
open(unit=2,file="vishal.rtp_entry",status="old",action="read")

read(2,*)
read(2,*)
11 format(F6.3)
do e=1, 259
    read(2,*)a(e),b(e),c(e),d(e)

    xyz = sum(\c(e)\)
    write(*,11)xyz(e)
    end do

close(2)

end program sum
```

Where do I need to correct my code? Thanks

Comment: try `sum(c)` after the loop

Comment: It didn't work as I have already tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you should see is that you are running both `sum` and `write(*,11)` for every iteration of the loop (i.e. for every input line).

That's almost certainly not what you want.

Since you are already storing all values, you might as well build the sum after the loop:

```
do e = 1, 259
    read(2, *) a(e),b(e),c(e),d(e)
end do
xyz = sum(c)
write(*, 11) xyz
```

Which brings me to the next point: `xyz` is declared as an integer **scalar**, but in the write statement you're calling it like an array. That must fail.

Next, `xyz` is an integer, but the `c` array is an array of `real` -- I think you should stick with one.

Then, you're using `unit=2`, which is dangerous, as different compilers might use unit 2 for other things. I usually stick to numbers larger than 10, or, even better, use `newunit=<variable>` which means that the compiler is selecting a good unit for me.

But if all you want is that one sum, you can do it a lot easier than that (and more flexible as to the number of lines the input file can have):

```
program my_sum
     implicit none
     character :: a, b
     real :: c
     integer :: d, e
     real :: accumulator
     integer :: ios ! Status for read commands to test for EOF

     open(unit=11, file="vishal.rtp_entry", status="old", action="read")

     accumulator = 0.0

     do
         read(11, *, iostat=ios) a, b, c, d, e
         if (ios /= 0) exit
         accumulator = accumulator + c
     end do

     close(11)

     write(*, '(F6.3)') accumulator

end program my_sum
```

Comment: Thanks, @chw21. After small modification of the code, it worked very well for me.

Comment: @Vishal If an answer answered your question, you should accept it, so that othes know that the question has been answered, and the poster of the answer gets credit where it's due.